# WPF RichTextBox bolding of Text From Code Efficiently

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox

Im brand new to WPF, so please excuse my ignorance, I have tried googling this issue for about 30 min+ and can't seem to find a simple solution that fits my scenario.

Basically Im making an IRC app that reads a line from the server, I read the nick, and the message. And put a line like :

```
<Nick> Message typed...
```

I want the `<Nick>` part in bold. And later on maybe in a colour. Also I saw some examples doing for each loops, but if I have a 1000+ lines and do a foreach loop everytime someone types something will that not be inefficent?

Please advise as to best / easiest approach ... from the c# programming side.

Here is my code :

```
    private void OnChannelMessage(object sender, IrcEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtActivity.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            txtActivity.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                  {
                      txtActivity.AppendText(string.Format("<Bold><{0}:{1}></Bold> {2}\n", e.Data.Channel, e.Data.Nick, e.Data.Message));

                      //Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                      //p.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(string.Format("<{0}> ", e.Data.Nick))));
                      //p.Inlines.Add(new Run(string.Format("{0}\n", e.Data.Message)));
                      //txtActivity.Document.Blocks.Add(p); // problem adds a big space between lines.
                  }
            ));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Name="txtActivity" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="12,12,12,41" BorderThickness="2" FontFamily="Consolas">
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>
    </RichTextBox>
    <Button Content="Quit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="628,371,0,0" Name="btnQuit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="btnQuit_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a FlowDocument.   It supports markup with lots of formatting.

[FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx)